# android.view.View.findViewById(int) on a null object reference (Android Lint)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a problem. I run Lint in android studio and it repaired some parts of my app, but after this app cant start. It writes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cewe.martin.cewetracking/com.cewe.martin.cewetracking.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
```

and I can't find, where is the problem. I can't do Undo, because there are some changed files so i tried to remove parts, which are not typical for me, but it still won't start. Here is onCreate method of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d("START","DO IFU");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ScanFragment()).commit();
            Log.d("START","ZA GETSUPP");
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_scan);
        }
    }
```

You can see Log.d. The first one "DO IFU" shows, the second one no, so I think, that it could be in ScanFragment(). Code here:

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {

    private final EditText rucneKod = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.numberInput);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
        Button skenovaciTlacitko = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        skenovaciTlacitko.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                zapnoutSkener();
            }
        });

        Button rucne = view.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        View.OnFocusChangeListener ofcListener = new MyFocusChangeListener();
        rucneKod.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);

        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        rucne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rucneKod.getText().length() != 0) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    odeslat(rucneKod.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.pozadovanKod, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Can somebody see the problematic code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final EditText rucneKod = (EditText) 
getView().findViewById(R.id.numberInput);
```

is causing NPE. Put it inside `OnCreateView` and repace `getView()` with `view`

Answer (score 1):

> getView() return the view returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater,
>   ViewGroup, Bundle))

Doing this : `private final EditText rucneKod = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.numberInput);`

it calls getView before `onCreateView` function, it will be null wich is normal,

Try moving the instantiation inside `onCreateView` function

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

`private final EditText rucneKod = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.numberInput);`

You should call findViewById inside onCreateView, right after inflating the fragment's layout. 
`getView()` is null when the fragment is constructed, and the stored properties are initialized before onCreateView is called.